# Unable to autoload freerdp-shadow-cli

Tags: bash, xrdp, freerdp

**Xrdp** server on kali linux. Also there is installed **freerdp2-shadow-x11** to start the shadow session.
The shadow server is started with the freerdp-shadow-cli command in the terminal of a running xrdp session. And only so.Interactively on the command line with output.
I need it to run in the background from autoload along with the session of the user connected to the server.
Partially, I solved it with a script:

**#!/bin/bash
freerdp-shadow-cli -auth -port:3389 -may-interact > /dev/null 2>&1 &**

interactively, this script is executed and everything works, but if you add it to autoload **(.zshrc file)**, then the script will only run when you open the terminal with your hands.

And so, experts, the question is:
How can I make the script autoload?

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out myself
From the very beginning:

```
apt install freerdp2-shadow-x11
nano  /home/user/RDS.sh
```

RDS.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#gnome-terminal -e
freerdp-shadow-cli -auth -port:3389 -may-interact > /dev/null 
2>&1 &
```

cli:

```
chmod 755 RDS.sh
nano /home/user/.config/autostart/shadow.desktop
```

shadow.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=shadow
GenericName=A descriptive name
Comment=Some description about your script
Exec=/home/user/RDS.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

cli:

```
chmod 755 shadow.desktop
reboot
```

-may-interact  -only show desktop